# Entity property not changed when modifying JSF UIComponent

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, ejb

I have a `<h:dataTable>` with columns defined as this

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Price"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{p.price}" rendered="#{not p.editable}"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{p.price}" rendered="#{p.editable}"></h:inputText>
</h:column>
```

The `<h:dataTable>` is populated successfully with

```
<h:dataTable id="userTable" value="#{gnome.productList}" 
             var="p">
```

The backing bean `#gnome` is a `@ViewScoped` bean, and the `productList` is loaded in a postconstructor and has a normal getter.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    productList = gnomeFacade.findAll();
}

public List<Gnome> getProductList() {
    return productList;
}
```

The `<h:inputText>` is rendered when an `<h:commandLink>` is pressed, and it allows me to modify the data in the fields. The data is then supposed to be saved using a `<h:commandButton>` defined outside the `<h:dataTable>`,

```
<h:commandButton value="Save changes!" action="#{gnome.saveAction}"/>
```

which invokes this method

```
public String saveAction() {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: Trying to save edited gnome...");
    for (Gnome g : productList) {
        gnomeFacade.edit(g);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have added some debug printouts in the `gnomeFacade.edit()` method, to be able to view what data is being merged. None of the properties in the `productList` entities are being saved with their new values. My initial thought was that the `<h:dataTable>` was reiterating over the values of the `productList`, but since I have it loaded in a postconstructor, that should not be the issue?

Why aren't the values of the properties changing when I change the values in the `<h:inputText>`?

**Edit:**
Full .xhtml document:
https://pastee.org/75t3e

Comment: Do you mean that all the `Gnome` objects in the `productList` have kept their default values when used in the `saveAction` loop? This would be strange as your code seems ok. Maybe you can update your question with the complete xhtml and bean code or a link to a github repo containing the project code.

Comment: That is indeed what is happening! I've updated the question with a pastee-link to the full .xhtml document!

Comment: Strange stuff. I tested your xhtml code with the `Gnome` and `Product` classes you can see [here](https://pastee.org/p998e) and this works (I removed the `h:form` for adding a new product). Maybe you can look for differences to your bean code (e.g. check the imports).

Comment: The only difference between our codes is that my list of products is fetched from an entity, which shouldn't really be the issue. I'll try your code and see if I can modify my own in any way so it works, even though it'll be more like a guessing game from my part now!